# ¿Cómo crear una Barra de progreso utilizando pydub?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydub

Estoy haciendo un script que convierte un archivo de audio a "MP3" con el módulo Pydub.. El detalle es que a la hora de ejecutar el script no sucede nada o no hay algo que me indique como va el proceso, para eso investigue en la documentación oficial del módulo si hay algo que permita manipular los bytes para aplicarlo en una barra de progreso y no hay nada que me pueda ayudar.. ¿Alguna forma de como aplicar esto?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
song = AudioSegment.from_file("/home/mono/Música/audio.webm",format="webm")
song.export("/home/mono/Música/audio.mp3", format="mp3",bitrate="128k")
```

Comment: Bienvenido @ErickCasanOva a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No lo veo fácil. Tienes que entender que particularmente `export` hace uso de herramientas externas, por lo que aún modificando el código original de esta función, para implementar un status del proceso, sería muy complejo, saber el número de bytes procesados para construir un barra de progreso real.